# Homework management during the week with a day in which two tasks alternate

Tags: c#

I'm doing an application where every day of the week there is a task to be done.
On Fridays there are two tasks to be done that alternate every Friday.

For example I would like to get (only one activity for Friday):

```
Monday I do A
Tuesday I do B
...
Friday I do L
...
Monday I do A
Tuesday I do B
...
Friday I do S
...
Monday I do A
Tuesday I do B
...
Friday I do L
...
Monday I do A
Tuesday I do B
...
Friday I do S
...
```

Code:

```
 var day = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd", new CultureInfo("it-IT"));
 string task = "";

 switch (day)
 {
     case "lunedì":
         task = "A";
         break;

     case "martedì":
         task= "B";
         break;

     case "mercoledì":
         task= "C";
         break;

     case "giovedì":
         task= "D";
         break;

     case "venerdì":
         task= "L"/"S";
         break;

     case "sabato":
         task = "V";
         break;

     case "domenica":
         task = "NADA";
         break;
}
```

Comment: And your question is? How to alternate job on Friday?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Can you store/detect the last executed friday task? What if you skip a friday (due to power-failture, configuration error, ...)?

Comment: Btw, you could use [DayOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.dayofweek) property for `switch/case` instead of localized strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to do this through just a switch on the day of week. You'll also need to know what task you did the previous week.

I believe something like below would work.

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
string task = "";

switch (today.DayOfWeek)
{
    case DayOfWeek.Monday:
        task = "A";
    break;

    case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
        task = "B";
    break;

    case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
        task = "C";
    break;

    case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
        task = "D";
    break;

    case DayOfWeek.Friday:      
        task = (today - new DateTime(1900,1,1)).Days % 2 == 0 ? "L" : "S";
    break;

    case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
        task = "V";
    break;

    case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
        task = "NADA";
    break;
}
```

The key is this line:

```
task = (today - new DateTime(1900,1,1)).Days % 2 == 0 ? "L" : "S";
```

Taking the first day of 1900 as a point of reference, if the number of days since then is even, we do "L." Otherwise, we do "S." Since there are 7 days a week, we are guaranteed to alternate between odd and even days since the reference point.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run task "L" in one week, and task "S" in another. And are not concerned about controlling when to run "L" or "S". And can ignore when tasks are not run. And execute the same task if you run the code multiple times on the same day. In that case, calculate the number of weeks, from a reference date (actual date does not care), and determine odd or even:

```
        case "venerdì":
            task= (((DateTime.Now - DateTime.MinValue).Days / 7) % 2) == 0 ? "L" : "S";
            break;
```